# Search and zoom to street stretch: By NAME, FROM, TO

Tags: arcgis-desktop, oracle-dbms, zoom, road, search

I have a `streets` feature class that has `name`, `from`, and `to` fields. Using this feature class, I want to zoom to locations such as these:

1. Main St, from 1st Ave to 2nd Ave (single feature)
2. Main St, from 2nd Ave to 5th Ave (multiple features)

*Note: My street names aren't actually numerical in reality. I just used street names like 2nd Ave and 5th Ave because it's easy to imagine what comes in between.*

I can do a couple of *similar* things using the [Find tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/using-the-find-tool.htm):

- Search for a street by `name`
- Search for a specific address

However, these options aren't the same thing as searching for a street stretch, using the `from` and `to` in conjunction with the `name`.

How can I search & zoom to a street stretch using the `name`, `from`, and `to` fields?

---

*I don't know if it's relevant or not, but there is a fourth field, `sort` (integer) that orders the features from west to east, south to north.*

Comment: I suppose scenario #1 could be described as `search and zoom (for single feature)
 using multiple fields`. But scenario #2 is a little more complicated than that.

Comment: It is network analyst task to find route between nodes.

Answer (score 2):

For scenario 2 you can try Select by attributes using the expression:

```
"Name"='Main St' AND left("From",1) > 1 AND left("From",1) < 5
```

I don't use ArcGIS anymore (cheapskate company moved to QGIS) so I can't test the expression. Should point you in the right direction though

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My street names aren't actually numerical in reality. I just used street names like 2nd Ave and 5th Ave because it's easy to imagine what comes in between.

Answer (score 0):

I can use a `subquery` when **selecting by attributes**. This query makes use of the `sort` field.

```
objectid in
(SELECT objectid FROM roads 
WHERE   
    name = 'Main St'
    AND sort Between 
                (select sort from roads where name = 'Main St' and from_ = '2nd Ave')
                and (select sort from roads where name = 'Main St' and to_ = '5th Ave'))
```

I use a similar technique in a question here: [Select rows where column values don't match the domain](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254134/select-rows-where-column-values-dont-match-the-domain).

The holy grail would be something with parameters such as a **python add-in**. But I'm horrible with python, so I'm not going to attempt this right now.